# How to shorten this JavaScript code [replace / regex]

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, unicode

The job of this code is to convert any number in the text into Unicode and the number itself.

This is the code below

```
"5H6i".replace(/[1-9]/g, function(match) {return match + String.fromCharCode(Number(match) + 32)});
```

for example:

> 3H4i Converted to 3#H4$i

Comment: Use an arrow function and a unary `+` for the conversion. It's not much shorter (23 characters less) but seems like the only thing to really do. Why does it need to be shorter, though? I don't really see problem with this code as it is. If it was on two or three lines it'd be more readable than it currently is as you don't have to scroll but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want it shorter, it's fine as it is. But here you go

```
"5H6i".replace(/[1-9]/g, match => match + String.fromCharCode(Number(match) + 32))
```